# ¿Cómo usar contours apropiadamente?

Tags: python, opencv

he estado intentando detectar el contorno de una pantalla de un medidor de presión arterial para poder leer los dígitos pero no logro hacerlo, adjunto una imagen. Sé que la iluminación afecta pero es difícil conseguir una buena imagen sin que salga algún reflejo.
El programa detecta 6 contornos.
Gracias de antemano.

```
import imutils
import cv2

image= cv2.imread("image.jpg")
image= imutils.resize(image, height=400)
blurred = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(image,50,50)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blurred,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret , threshold = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

_, contours,_=cv2.findContours
(threshold,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
print "Number of contours detected %d -> "%len(contours)

cv2.drawContours(image,contours,-1,(255,255,255),3)

cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Contorno]

Adjunto la original
[image: Original]

Comment: Sería bueno que adjuntes la imagen original, sin los contornos ya dibujados. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que tu objetivo sería de alguna manera "aislar" el LCD para luego poder interpretar los dígitos. Bien, ya te habrás dado cuenta que la detección de contornos se complica cuando hay muy poca separación de colores, entre las letras, el LCD y el marco exterior. Pensando en el objetivo final es que me animo a sugerirte otra aproximación al problema  que puede llegar funcionar. La idea sería trabajar sobre los colores de los dígitos para convertirlos en puntos blancos y al resto de los colores en negro, una forma de "aislar" la información que nos interesa.

En primer lugar, con alguna herramienta de edición de imágenes habría que averiguar los colores RGB de los dígitos del LCD, tomaremos varias muestras hasta poder determinar un rango. Esto ya lo hice y para la imagen del ejemplo que diste un rango RGB de (16,17,9) a (51,37,25) cubre bastante bien las información de los caracteres del LCD. Por supuesto hay otros patrones que tendrán esos colores, hay que buscar un equilibrio, logrando la mayor cantidad de información para poder luego detectar los dígitos y minimizar lo más posible la información (pixels) innecesaria. Con estos datos vamos a filtrar estos colores, creando una nueva imagen solo con los pixels dentro de ese rango de colores:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("presion.jpg")

############################################################################
# Me quedo solo con un concjunto de colores que representan aproximadamente
# los colores de los números en el LCD
############################################################################
lower = np.array([9, 17, 16])  #-- Lower range --
upper = np.array([25, 37, 51])  #-- Upper range --
image = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Interesante, no? si además quieres leer las pulsaciones, te recomiendo ampliar un poco los limites de los colores para poder recuperar mayor cantidad de pixels de dicho número, por ahora, a modo de ejemplo me voy a concentrar solo en los números de la medición sistólica y diastólica.

La siguiente mejora, es [`dilate()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate), un algoritmo  que justamente como nos sirve para "engrosar" los patrones detectados.

```
############################################################################
# Dilate - Engrosamos un poco los patrones
############################################################################
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
image = cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations=1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahora viene lo interesante, usaremos [`connectedComponentsWithStats()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga107a78bf7cd25dec05fb4dfc5c9e765f) para limpiar un poco la imagen, básicamente vamos a dejar patrones de pixels que estuvieran conectados y que tienen un mínimo de superficie o realmente de cantidad de pixels. Por último otro [`dilate()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate) para que nos quede algo mejor.

```
############################################################################
# Quitamos artefactos que tengan menos de cierta "superficie"
############################################################################
min_size = 2000 # En pixels
nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image, connectivity=8)
sizes = stats[1:, -1]; nb_components = nb_components - 1
clean_mask = np.zeros((output.shape))
for i in range(0, nb_components):
  if sizes[i] >= min_size:
    clean_mask[output == i + 1] = 255

############################################################################
# Dilate - Volvemos a engrosar la imagen
############################################################################
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
clean_mask = cv2.dilate(clean_mask, kernel, iterations=1)
```

Y el resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto, entiendo que ya podrías intentar alguna técnica de reconocimiento de patrones para "leer" realmente los datos.